# Delete Images -> codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have reworded my question to help gain my specific answer, sorry if my last question was confusing:

I  have an issue with trying to delete a row from the database but also incorporate how to unlink the to images from different locations.  I cannot get the row to delete or the images to unlink.

Here is my -> **[db structure](http://cl.ly/292t2t0B001h0Y0C1y1v)**

**My image locations are:**

```
fullpath = /includes/uploads/gallery/

thumbpath = /includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/
```

**Ideal Situation:**

What my ideal situation would be is when the delete link is clicked that it will run the function within the index function and then reload the same page with a success message -> I have not successfully been able to get them to work.

**My code:**

**Model:**

```
function deleteImage($id,$path){

        $this->db->delete('images', array('id' => $id));

        if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1) {
            if(unlink($path)
                return TRUE;
            } else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

**View:**

```
    <?php if(is_array($get_images)): ?>

            <?php foreach($get_images as $image): ?>
            <img src ="<?=base_url()?>includes/uploads/gallery/thumbs/<?=$image->thumbpath?>" alt="<?= $image->description?>"> <a href="deleteimage/delete/<?=$image->id?>">Delete</a>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Controller:**

```
   function index() { 
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { 
        redirect('admin/home'); 
    } 
    // Main Page Data 
    $page['get_images'] = $this->image_model->getImages();
    $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
    $data['title'] = 'Delete Gallery Image'; 
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/deleteimage',$page,TRUE); 

    $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for if you're using active record is:

$this->db->delete();

Now from memory this will only return false if an error has occurred, so will constantly return true. But it's ok we can use another function to check whether the row was deleted.

Oh and you will also want to pass into the function the path of the file you want deleting.

```
function deleteImage($id,$path) {

$this->db->delete('table', array('id' => $id));

    if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1){
        if(unlink($path))
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey,  How could I make it delete from a certain location,  I have only saved the file names into the db and I have a thumbs and full image row.

Answer (score 4):

```
function delete_data($record_id)
{
    $query =  $this->db->get_where('projukti_committee',array('record_id' => $record_id));
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $picture = $row->picture;
        unlink(realpath('assets/photo/'.$picture));
        $this->db->delete('projukti_committee', array('record_id' => $record_id));
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: A supreme solution, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have an image ID of some sort.

Append the ID to the `deleteimage/delete` URI.

Create a method that deletes the ID from your table, and use PHP's `unlink($path)` function to actually delete the image.

Comment: I am about to update my question - lets say I have walked away and I am now kicking myself haha

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 doh you are correct, got myself confused when I read OP's post, who mentioned *unset*! Have corrected myself.

Comment: I know... comment removed, +1 stays :)